# rospack can not find my plugin

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS and write a global planner plugin. my package is robocars, my class name is robocars::PathFollowingGlobalPlanner. Here is my package.xml:

```
<export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
    <!-- <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/path_following_global_planner_plugin.xml" /
>-->
    <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/path_following_global_planner_plugin.xml" />
  </export>
```

And here is my path_following_global_planner_plugin.xml

```
<library path="lib/libpath_following_global_planner_lib">
  <class name="robocars/PathFollowingGlobalPlanner" type="robocars::PathFollowin
gGlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>This is a global planner plugin by robocars project.</descripti
on>
  </class>
 </library>
```

PathFollowingGlobalPlanner class compiled fine. "rospack find robocars" can find my package. But when I run "rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core", the plugin did not show up.

Why

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298919/rospack-can-not-find-my-plugin/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your package.xml -- do you have the dependency on nav_core? In order to be picked up by rospack, your package must depend directly on nav_core, the package which defines the plugin type.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-28**:
Yeah, you are right. I had only <build_depend>, not . After I add that, rospack picked it up.

Thank you very much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-29**:
And just for completeness: see the [pluginlib wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.Registering_Plugin_with_ROS_Package_System) where this is documented (from #q163476).